# Using google account to sign in using Oauth 2.0

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am building a web app where I have integrated log in with Google+ account using Oauth authentication. This does not let users who don't have a Google plus account sign in unless they sign up with Google plus. I would like to let users sign in with a valid Google email address instead of a Google+ account so that a user who is not signed up with Google+ does not have to do sign up. I didn't find anywhere on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [incremental authorization](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/incremental-auth) with the [basic profile scope](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes).